# Material-ui features wont work with upgrade to v1.0.0-beta

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I switched from v0.19 to v1.0.0-beta.21, and when i do something like

```
import  { Component } from 'react';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
class App extends Component {
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">
        <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
      </div>
      <p className="App-intro">
        To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
      </p>
      <Button>Example Button</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

}

I get the error of

```
VM2536:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Button is not defined
at eval (eval at App (App.js:12), <anonymous>:1:1)
at App (App.js:12)
at beginWork (react-dom.production.min.js:149)
at e (react-dom.production.min.js:182)
at k (react-dom.production.min.js:183)
at p (react-dom.production.min.js:184)
at y (react-dom.production.min.js:188)
at D (react-dom.production.min.js:187)
at Object.updateContainer (react-dom.production.min.js:248)
at react-dom.production.min.js:254
```

In fact, I can not load in any component from the new material-ui library.

I believe I am using the new verison of material.ui because my package.json dependencies are:

```
  "dependencies": {
...
"material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.21",
"material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
...
```

}

**EDIT:**

The above error is misleading. In fact I am able to load in elements from material-ui. When I do `console.log(Button)` it is clear that it is loaded. It seems like the issue is that non of the styles are loaded into the element. It just shows up as a plain looking button. If I add a `<AppBar label="title"/>` for example, none of the styles show up and just shows up as  something like `<h1>title</h1>`.

Comment: What happens if you `npm list material-ui`?

Comment: it shows `-- material-ui@1.0.0-beta.21. Please look above for my edit

Comment: Are your elements contained within a `<MuiThemeProvider>`?

Comment: Do you need MuiThemeProvider in v1.0.0?

Comment: Yes, you do. Blah blah blah extra text to make this long enough to submit.

Comment: still doesnt work...